# apt full-upgrade from Debian 10 to 11: missed selection of trusted certificates or something, how to fix it?

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

I was following this guide to update debian 10 to 11 on my server:
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/upgrade-debian-10-to-11

During step 6:

```
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

I got a screen with a text-based (G)UI that said something like (I'm quoting from memory):

> [...] Some certificates will be installed [...]
>
> Select the ones you trust:

and there was a **list of checkboxes** with names such as Mozilla and others, and then an "OK" button at the end.

So, I meant to check all the checkboxes. Since I could only use the keyboard, I moved the text cursor to the first checkbox with the arrow keys, and **I hit Enter** with the intention of selecting the checkbox.

Because apparently the person who designed this (G)UI is a genius, hitting Enter resulted in submitting the form (with no checkbox checked or perhaps the first one) instead of checking the checkbox that my cursor was on.

So now, I guess, none of the certificates is "trusted" (hopefully they will still be "installed", at least that's what it said), whatever that means.

My question is:

- How do I correct that?

Comment: The default key for checkbox selection is `spacebar`.  With no mouse use `Tab` to select the proper area of the screen, then `spacebar` and `Arrow Keys`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package that asked such question is most likely [`ca-certificates`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/ca-certificates):

> Package: ca-certificates (20210119)
>
> Common CA certificates
>
> Contains the certificate authorities shipped with Mozilla's browser to
> allow SSL-based applications to check for the authenticity of SSL
> connections.

To trigger asking again the same questions for a package, the command is [`dpkg-reconfigure`](https://manpages.debian.org/debconf/dpkg-reconfigure.8):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> `dpkg-reconfigure` reconfigures packages after they have already been
> installed. Pass it the names of a package or packages to reconfigure.
> It will ask configuration questions, much like when the package was
> first installed.

So just run:

```
dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

in a terminal to get again the interactive questions (plus by default possibly lower priority questions, which should be kept to their default if their meaning is not known) about enabling certificates and get the occasion to change previous choices.

Comment: Btw, the *official* documentation for upgrading debian 10 to 11 (on amd64): https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading . For the next time, debian 11 to 12: https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading  . There are more details about the actions to do, and it certainly won't advise to use `-y`.